# Issue with bindingsource refresh after row insert - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

Windows Form Application,
VS 2010 C#,
Access 2003

I am referencing from this website, [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/d53ad3fa-effc-4c9a-8520-897ecd85aa5f/). My aim is to show updated records (insert/delete update) without closing and restarting the application to show new reflection. I have quite a few textboxes, comboxes etc, so I am not using datagridview.

From that website there are two pieces of code...

```
bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bdSource;
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bdSource;
```

So I did this...

```
this.table1BindingSource = dbSource;
```

and gave a error of "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**."  With a warning that **dbSource is never assigned and will aways have a default value null**.

my insert command parameter structure..

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, Name) VALUES(@ID, @Name)", myCon);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
myCon.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
myCon.Close();
```

The following method I am hoping data would be refreshed...

```
private void btnReload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  OleDbDataAdapter.Update(dtSource);
}
```

and...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private OleDbConnection myCon;
    private string connectionString;
    private string commandText;
    private OleDbCommandBuilder OleDbCommandBuilder;
    private OleDbDataAdapter OleDbDataAdapter;
    private DataTable dtSource;
    private BindingSource dbSource;

 public Form1()
    {
     connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data.. ";
     commandText = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1";

    myCon = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    OleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(commandText, myCon);
    OleDbCommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(OleDbDataAdapter);

   dtSource = new DataTable();
   OleDbDataAdapter.Fill(dtSource);

        dbSource = new BindingSource();
        dbSource.DataSource = dtSource;
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who could help me

**EDIT**
I also have navigation buttons..

```
  private void fnDisplayPosition()
    {
        this.label2.Text = this.table1BindingSource.Position + 1 + " of " + 
        this.table1BindingSource.Count;
        table1BindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
    }
```

then in the Form load...

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.fnDisplayPosition();
    }
```

Example of navigation button...

```
  private void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.table1BindingSource.MoveFirst();
        this.fnDisplayPosition();
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**
I did some error in coding so warning signs and errors are gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, here you initalize bindingSource called **bdSource**

```
 bdSource = new BindingSource();
```

But then you try to set the dataSource

```
 dbSource.DataSource = dtSource;
```

for bindingSource called **dbSource**.You haven't initalized it yet. So, which one of them you are going to use?

Also, what is     `table1BindingSource` in your code?

Comment: I have noted in the partial class I have two identical private declaration of binding source. So I removed one of them. Perhaps I have misread from that website. I am looking at it again. Also I am looking at how to initialize binding source

Comment: You've already done that by this: `bdSource = new BindingSource();`, but only for one of those bindingSources. I meant that you have to set dataSource for bindinigSource that you've already initalized, so, to write something like `dbSource = new BindingSource(); dbSource.DataSource = ...`

Comment: table1BindingSource is doing nothing So I got rid of it. I have done dbSource.DataSource = dtSource; have I not?

Comment: You should only set the DataSource property for the control you are using further. Thus, if you are going to use dbSource, type `dbSource.DataSource = dtSource`. If you are going to use bdSource, type `bdSource.DataSource = dtSource`. Then, you should set the dataGridView1.DataSource property to the source you have already initialized.

Comment: I am not entirely sure but the solution of the problem has been solved which error message and a warning sign. thanks.But the problem remains that new data is not refreshing so I don't if I should open a new tread?

Comment: I am not using dataGridView And that is what I did. I think I have created confusion with my typing so hopefully my update makes sense, does it not?

Comment: Yeah, it makes). But it doesn't matter which control you use to present data - it may be listView, comboBox or something else. I meant their property DataSource, cause for setting it up you should use initialized list of data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27720/discussion-between-bucketblast-and-mr-zak)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with tableadapters and bindingsource tied to texboxes and others alike. I have explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885244/textboxes-not-refreshing-after-insert-command-parameter) in full.