# textboxes not refreshing after insert command parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

Access 2003, VS 2010 C#, Windows Form Application

I think I am having this problem because my textboxes etc are databind to the current data so the question is how do I get the binding source to read new data without having to close and restart the application? There are no error(s).  I have tried number of ways but they all don't show new record while the application is currently running so what am I doing wrong?

My Form Load looks like this..

```
 this.fnDisplayPosition();

 bdSource = new BindingSource();
 string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
 OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, myCon);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 da.Fill(ds, "Table1");

 bdSource.DataSource = ds;
 //  this.table1BindingSource.AddNew();
 txtID.DataBindings.Add("Text", bdSource, "ID");
 cBAG.DataBindings.Add("Text", bdSource, "AgeGroup");
 cBGender.DataBindings.Add("Text", bdSource, "Gender");
```

The fnDisplayPosition method reads how many records there which is tied to the databinding...

```
this.label7.Text = this.table1BindingSource.Position + 1 + " of " +   
this.table1BindingSource.Count;
```

As example this is my navigation button..

```
 this.table1BindingSource.MoveFirst();
 this.fnDisplayPosition();
```

The following is my insert method and I am able to add new record I have used from [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/Insertcommandwithparameters.htm) website...

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, AgeGroup, Gender)VALUES
(@txtID, @cBAG, @cBGender", myCon);

       string qry = @"select * from Table1";
       string upd = @"INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, AgeGroup, Gender)   
                      VALUES(@txtID, @cBAG, @cBGender)";

 myCon.Open();

       try
         {
           da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(qry, myCon);
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           da.Fill(ds, "Table1");

           DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Table1"];

           DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
           newRow["ID"] = txtID;
           newRow["AgeGroup"] = cBAG;
           newRow["Gender"] = cBGender;
           dt.Rows.Add(newRow);

           OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(upd, myCon);

           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtID.Text);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgeGroup", cBAG.Text);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", cBGender.Text);

           da.InsertCommand = cmd;
           da.Update(ds, "Table1");
           da.Fill(ds, upd);
           } catch(Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
     } finally {
       myCon.Close();
     }
```

Comment: either my code is absolute rubbish or nobody knows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trial and errors I found what why it was happening. The usage of tableadapters and binding source tied to textboxes others alike is not the way to go. You have to hard code. So to see the you data reflection whether it's update, delete or adding new record without closing and restating your application, you cannot use tableadapters or binding source. To clearly understand what I am saying, do you this website, [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/e628d9/inserting-retrieving-records-from-ms-access-2007-using-odbc/). It doesn't matter what connection you are using or how you use your command parameters. Well anyway it is only my opinion.